# Asp.net MVC core custom tag helper not generate output

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I implemented a custom tag helper to generate page numbers as a link. The "Process" method is triggered and the string builder has all the HTML content in it but it does not output the result on the screen. It just renders  , Could anyone help, please?

```
<paginate page="Model.PageInfo" />



[HtmlTargetElement("paginate",
     TagStructure = TagStructure.WithoutEndTag)]
    public class PaginateTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public PageInfo Page { get; set; }
        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
            html.Append("<div>");
            for (int i = 1; i <= Page.TotalPages; i++)
            {
                var tag = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.TagBuilder("a");
                tag.MergeAttribute("href", Page.PageUrl(i));
                tag.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(i.ToString());
                if (i == Page.CurrentPage)
                {
                    tag.AddCssClass("selected");
                    tag.AddCssClass("btn-primary");
                }
                tag.AddCssClass("btn btn-default");
                html.Append(GetTagContent(tag));
            }
            html.Append("</div>");
            output.Content.SetHtmlContent(html.ToString());
        }
        private string GetTagContent(IHtmlContent content)
        {
            using (var writer = new System.IO.StringWriter())
            {
                content.WriteTo(writer, System.Text.Encodings.Web.HtmlEncoder.Default);
                return writer.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you registered the custom tag helper in the `_ViewImports.cshtml` or in the corresponding view?

Comment: Of course I did. As I mentioned the process method is called.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `TagStructure = TagStructure.WithoutEndTag`, self closing tags are not suitable for tags with inner content.

> #### [Self-closing TagHelpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1#self-closing-tag-helpers)
>
> Many Tag Helpers can't be used as self-closing tags. Some Tag Helpers are designed to be self-closing tags. Using a Tag Helper that was not designed to be self-closing suppresses the rendered output. Self-closing a Tag Helper results in a self-closing tag in the rendered output.

Comment: Worked. Thank you